# Pass parameter to parent or sub template

Tags: playframework-2.0

In my index method I render a basic login form, that I sent to my **index.scala.html**:

```
/**
 * Main entry method for the application
 */
public static Result index() {
     return ok(views.html.index.render(form(Application.Login.class)));
}
```

In the file **index.scala.html**: I have defined the **form** parameter:

```
@(form: Form[Application.Login])

@main(title = "myTitle") {
    <h2>Testing app</h2>
}
```

So, in this file I call the parent template by **@main(...)**. But how to pass the **form** to my parent template? I have tried the following:

```
@(form: Form[Application.Login])

@main(title = "myTitle", form) {
    <h2>Testing app</h2>
}
```

and the in my **main.scala.html** the following:

```
@(title: String, form: Form[Application.Login])(content: Html)
```

But this is not working, I get the following error message:

```
not enough arguments for method apply: (title: java.lang.String, form: play.data.Form[controllers.Application.Login])(content: play.api.templates.Html)play.api.templates.Html in object main. Unspecified value parameter form.
```

---

Comment: It’s probably an issue due to the usage of named parameters. Try `@main(title = "myTitle", form = form) { … }` or just `@main("myTitle", form) { … }`

Comment: Julien, yes it is working. Just needed to clean and run my app. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Julien stated this is working:

```
@main(title = "myTitle", form = form) { … } or just @main("myTitle", form) { … }
```